# One class extends another in spring boot and mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, extends

I am a little lost in this situation.
I have a class named User and a class UserProfile, I want to UserProfile extends User.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="user_profile")
public class UserProfile extends User{
    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name="age")
    private String age;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;
}
```

I have these 2 repositories

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    User findByEmail(String email);
    ...
}

public interface UserProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<UserProfile, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT u FROM UserProfile u WHERE u.email = :email")
    UserProfile getUserProfile(String email);
    ...
}
```

And this is my sql

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  email varchar(255) NOT NULL unique,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE user_profile(
  gender varchar(20),
  age varchar(3),
  user_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
);
```

When I try to "getUserProfile":

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        u1_0.id,
        u1_0.email,
        u1_0.name,
        u1_0.age,
        u1_0.gender,
        u1_0.user_id,
    from
        user u1_0 
    where
        u1_0.email=? 
        and u1_0.dtype='UserProfile'
```

I got "Unknown column 'u1_0.age' in 'field list'", so I am missing something.
Can someone help me?

Comment: You need `@MappedSuperclass`, I would guess https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-inherit-properties-from-a-base-class-entity-using-mappedsuperclass-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I tryed to use this, but I got other classes that use User as a foreign key, then I got this error: "Association 'com.lifes.appmental.models.Contact.user' targets an unknown entity named 'com.lifes.appmental.models.User"